# Flask-Admin Stores NULL in Database Instead of empty string ('')

Tags: python-3.x, flask-admin

Title says it all. Using flask-admin and would like to store an empty string in my database instead of NULL but when I leave a field blank in flask-admin it enters NULL in the database. If I type '' into the flask-admin view, the database stores that as "''" in the database.

I am NOT asking about how to display an empty string in the flask-admin view as a lot of other people have asked about. I am asking what I should type into the flask-admin view or what code I should change in order to store an empty string in my database from the flask-admin view.

The reason I need to do this is parts of my code validates the table column at issue for '' (an empty string). Example: db.tablename.query.filter_by(complete=''). One option is to change all my validation to db.tablename.query.filter_by(complete=None), but I would like to keep all my code consistent in validating for '' and it would be a lot to change all the validation lines to None so it would be most helpful if I knew how to set a table cell to a blank string from the flask-admin view.

Using python3.6

Answer (score 2):

To override this behaviour you can create a new field class:

```
import wtforms.fields

class StringField(wtforms.fields.StringField):
    def process_data(self, value):
        self.data = value or ''
```

`process_data` method receives and stores form data. If it receives `None` it will store it as `''`. To use this logic in your view add this class to the `form_overrides` attribute:

```
class MyView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = {
        'my_field': StringField,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the column in your ORM as nullable=False. Flask Admin makes the quite correct assumption that, if a column is nullable, an empty field must be converted to None. Instead, if a column is NOT nullable, an empty field is converted to `''`.